# Inserting a date in a column of date datatype in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-insert, string-to-datetime

How can I insert a date of format `dd-mm-yyyy` into a column of datatype `Date`?

Tried the below but showing errors

```
INSERT INTO Profiles (first_name, last_name, email, phone, 
                      [city(hometown)], created_at, gender, 
                      referral_code,marital_status) 
VALUES ('anusha', 'pariti', 'anusha.pariti@gmail.com', '8105987404', 
        'Bangalore', '16-04-2015', 'F', '7L5FZW', 'Y'),
       ('Ashish', 'Singh', 'ashish.singh@gmail.com', '9876890463', 
        'Bangalore','23-05-2015', 'M', 'KF34MF', 'Y')
```

*Error:*

> Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.

```
INSERT INTO Profiles (first_name, last_name, email, phone, 
                      [city(hometown)],created_at, gender, 
                      referral_code, marital_status) 
VALUES ('anusha', 'pariti', 'anusha.pariti@gmail.com', '8105987404', 
        'Bangalore', CAST('16-04-2015' AS DATE), 'F', '7L5FZW', 'Y'),
       ('Ashish', 'Singh', 'ashish.singh@gmail.com', '9876890463', 
        'Bangalore', CAST('23-05-2015' AS DATE), 'M', 'KF34MF', 'Y')
```

*Error:*

> Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.

```
INSERT INTO Profiles (first_name, last_name, email, phone, 
                      [city(hometown)], created_at, gender,  
                      referral_code, marital_status) 
VALUES ('anusha', 'pariti', 'anusha.pariti@gmail.com', '8105987404', 
        'Bangalore', CONVERT(DATE, '16-04-2015'), 'F', '7L5FZW', 'Y'),
       ('Ashish', 'Singh', 'ashish.singh@gmail.com', '9876890463', 
        'Bangalore', CONVERT(DATE, '23-05-2015'), 'M', 'KF34MF', 'Y')
```

*Error:*

> Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.

Answer (score 2):

Try inserting your dates using an acceptable format, e.g. use `20150416` instead of `'16-04-2015`:

```
INSERT INTO Profiles (first_name, last_name, email, phone, [city(hometown)],
    created_at, gender, referral_code,marital_status)
VALUES
    ('anusha', 'pariti', 'anusha.pariti@gmail.com', '8105987404', 'Bangalore',
     '20150416', 'F', '7L5FZW', 'Y'),
    ('Ashish', 'Singh', 'ashish.singh@gmail.com', '9876890463', 'Bangalore',
     '20150523', 'M', 'KF34MF', 'Y');
```

This will allow you store the data as dates inside the `created_at` column.  This is absolutely the way to store your date information.  If you later want to *format* the `created_at` column in your original way, you could use `CONVERT`, e.g.

```
SELECT
    CONVERT(varchar, created_at, 105) AS created_at
FROM Profiles;
```

Comment: Yes the acceptable format is working. But what if i want the format as specified i.e 16-04-2015. Is there a way to insert it in that format?

Comment: Not that I know of.  In any case, why would you even want to do that?  The formats are wrong and you would have to do verbose conversions later on.

Comment: @Biswa you can't insert the date ('16-04-2015') as per your need in datetime field, but later you can read as per your required format.

Comment: Ok. Thats what i wanted to know if it was possible in anyway. Thanks

Comment: It is possible for date literals of YYYY-MM-DD to fail in MSSQL refer to https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/16/bad-habits-to-kick-mis-handling-date-range-queries  While it may be non-standard, and not intuitive, date literals of YYYYMMDD are always safe to use (in MSSQL!).

Answer (score 1):

The safest date literal in SQL Server is YYYYMMDD

E.g.
INSERT into ... Values ('20170523', ...

It seems you are used to DD-MM-YYYY and if you want to use that sequence you then need to use convert with a style number.

convert(date, '23-05-2017',120)

Comment: It is bad advice to suggest inserting dates as text, despite that your conversion logic might work.

Comment: Then you are attempting to insert an invalid date value like the 30th of February. The error message can be encountered simply because a string just will not become a date.

Comment: By the way you MUST include the stule number when using CONVERT(date,'2015-05-23',120)  if you dont include that third parameter you are relying on default settings which wont help you. Also not thst dates are stored as numbers, not in a human readable format.  Formats matter at input and can be changed to suit output.

Comment: @Tim_Biegeleisen  In MSSQL 'YYYYMMDD" is actually safer than 'YYYY-MM-DD' because there is one (albeit very uncommon) default that can be set which would interpret the date as 'YYYY-DD-MM'. So it is bad advice to propose a 'YYYY-MM-DD' literal whereas 'YYYYMMDD' is always interpreted in that sequence. Personally I hate it, just happens to be the way it is.

Answer (score 0):

In SQL server 2012+ you can use

```
Select try_convert(date, '16-04-2015', 105)
```

otherwise you have to format the string correctly

Comment: This might work but the easier solution would be to just use an ISO format for the date strings.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried YYYY-MM-DD format? The data format in SQL is YYYY-MM-DD.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this.

`dd-mm-yyyy` is Italian format and style code is 105, that's why you should convert it by using this code.

```
INSERT INTO Profiles (first_name, last_name, email, phone, 
                      [city(hometown)], created_at, gender,  
                      referral_code, marital_status) 
VALUES ('anusha', 'pariti', 'anusha.pariti@gmail.com', '8105987404', 
        'Bangalore', CONVERT(DATE, '16-04-2015',105), 'F', '7L5FZW', 'Y'),
       ('Ashish', 'Singh', 'ashish.singh@gmail.com', '9876890463', 
        'Bangalore', CONVERT(DATE, '23-05-2015',105), 'M', 'KF34MF', 'Y')
```